# Javascript Object Inconsistency

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider an object called `obj` that I believe to be equal to `{x: 1, y: 'hi'}` (It was defined a while ago, and has undergone some modifications through various functions throughout its lifetime).

```
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.y);
console.log(obj.x);
```

The result of this in both Chrome and FF3.6 shows the result of `console.log(obj)` as

```
obj = {x: 1, y: 'hi'}
```

as expected. The result of `obj.y` prints `hi` as expected, but the result of `obj.x` prints `0`.

I do not understand how this inconsistency can happen. It prints correctly as the object as a whole, but then on the very next line prints a different value upon accessing the parameter directly.

I assume this has something to do with shared object structure, because I define `obj` and store it in an array `arr`. Then I put `obj` on a DOM element using jQuery's `.data()` function. I later retrieve the object using `.data()` from the DOM element and modify the object some more (parameter `x` specifically). The oddities I am seeing are happening when I later go access the object from `arr`.

Mostly, I just want to understand why the console.log shows an inconsistency

Comment: It is impossible to tell without some live demo. If I create an object like this, `obj.x` prints `1`. I.e. I cannot reproduce the error... please provide a demonstration of the problem.

Comment: I don't think that I have enough information to know what is going wrong.  From what you describe you should get references to the same object when you access it using .data() or retrieve it from an array.  What exactly are the manipulations that you are making to obj.x?

Comment: @Jesse just like obj.x = 2 or something

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch an object from ".data()", you do **not** get a copy of the object - you get the object itself. There's only one.  Thus, if you do this:

```
$('#foo').data('obj', { x: 1, y: "hi" });
```

and then:

```
var obj = $('#foo').data('obj');
// ...
if (whatever) obj.x = 0;
```

then later when you reference "obj" via ".data()" again, the "x" property will be zero (if the "if" condition had been true, in this case).

You can avoid this by making a copy of the data yourself, if what you *want* is a copy of course.

Comment: sure, but any ideas on why console.log shows two different results based on how I tell it to print?

Comment: I cannot duplicate that experience, so you must be doing something else that you haven't described.  When I do exactly what you suggested, I get expected answers printed by Chrome (that is, "x" is 1 in both renditions).